# Unchecked call to 'save(E)' as

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

MemberJoin Creadted
But Error

1. MemberController.java

   ```
    @Autowired
    private MemberSv memberSv;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/join", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String membersave(MemberDTO memberDTO)
    {
        memberSv.member_save(memberDTO);
        return "join_form";
    }
   ```
2. MemvberSv.java

   ```
    public interface MemberSv {
        MemberDTO member_save(MemberDTO memberDTO);
    }
   ```
3. MemberSvImp.java

   ```
    @Service
    public class MemberSvImp implements MemberSv {


        CommonRepository commonRepository;

        @Override
        public MemberDTO member_save(MemberDTO memberDTO) {
            commonRepository.save(memberDTO);
            return memberDTO;
        }


    }
   ```
4. CommonRepository.java

   ```
    @NoRepositoryBean
    public interface CommonRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends                                 
    MongoRepository<T, ID> {
        <E extends T> E save(E entity);
    }
   ```
5. Error
   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
   at

com.example.accountproject.models.services.MemberSvImp.member_save(MemberSvImp.java:19)
~[main/:na]

Comment: `CommonRepository commonRepository` is a raw type and not even marked to be injected by Spring.

Comment: Use constructor injection (with normal `final` fields) to prevent this and similar problems; you will immediately find what's wrong.